# Doubling up on spreadsheet

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have created a macro in excel below for work a related form that is supposed to hide the tabs, copy the file to the desktop as a xlsx, then reopen the original xlsm, unhide the tabs then clear the form.  My problem is that it opens a second Xlsm copy and places it on the desktop too.  It had worked for a month perfectly now, ether I messed something up or someone else did.  Is there anything that you can see in the script below.  Thank you

```
Sub SaveAs()                ATW spreadsheet
‘SaveAs
‘Hide Tabs– add ATW -authority number then contractor company to file title Save file as XLSX to Desktop. Reopen XLSM, and unhide tabs.
Application.DisplayAlerts = False       ‘ 
    Sheets(Array("Contractor info", "PTW", "DataBase")).Select
    Sheets("DataBase").Activate
    ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.Visible = False
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
        "C:\Users\U0154179\Desktop\ATW " & ActiveSheet.Range("B21").Value & "-" & ActiveSheet.Range("I3").Value & ".xlsx", FileFormat:= _
        xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
        "C:\Users\U0154179\Desktop\ATW Template.xlsm", _
            FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, CreateBackup:=False
    Sheets("ATW").Select
    Sheets("Contractor info").Visible = True
    Sheets("ATW").Select
    Sheets("PTW").Visible = True
    Sheets("ATW").Select
    Sheets("DataBase").Visible = True
    Sheets("ATW").Select
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason it's saving two copies to your desktop is because you have both your SaveAs calls pointing to the desktop.

Additionally, you almost never need to Select anything to work with it.

A quick modification of your code yields:

```
Sub SaveAs()
'SaveAs
'Hide Tabs– add ATW -authority number then contractor company to file title Save file as XLSX to Desktop. Reopen XLSM, and unhide tabs.
Dim OrignalFilename As String

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Sheets(Array("Contractor info", "PTW", "DataBase")).Visible = xlSheetHidden

OriginalFileName = ActiveWorkbook.FullName

ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs _
    Filename:="C:\Users\U0154179\Desktop\ATW " & ActiveSheet.Range("B21").Value & "-" & ActiveSheet.Range("I3").Value & ".xlsx", _
    FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook

Sheets("Contractor info").Visible = xlSheetVisible
Sheets("PTW").Visible = xlSheetVisible
Sheets("DataBase").Visible = xlSheetVisible

Sheets("ATW").Select

ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs _
    Filename:=OriginalFileName, _
    FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled

Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

Comment: I actually have 3 Macros that I am running and the ClrFrm is the last.  However I copied and pasted your revision and ;

Comment: I actually have 3 Macros that I am running and the ClrFrm is the last.  However I copied and pasted your revision and ; 1.  It wouldn't run with the sheet array so it reverted back to selecting the individual tabs and unhide them and that continued to work fine.  Actually it all worked well except I could not open the saved  .xlsx file.  It required me to change it to a . xls file with a pre warning popup.

Comment: It did not recognize the file extension, is why I had to change it to an xls.

Comment: Sorry, SaveCopyAs retains the format of the original file. I've updated the code to reflect the .xlsm extension.

Comment: I get what you are trying to do but by copying as an Xlsm won't work because I need it to be a xlsx.  This is because of the macro issue.  The company doesn't want multiple macros floating around in their network.

Comment: Fair enough, though keep in mind that the code will still be in the file, even if it's an xlsx. All someone has to do is change the extension and the macros will run again.

I've modified the code to preserve your extensions. Unfortunately you can't use SaveCopyAs in this case.

Comment: I loaded the revision and it worked like a charm.  Thank you for that.  Everyday is a learning experience.  I understand what your saying about the code.  All these files are internal to our closed network, the xlsx macros are all disabled and the people who view them are troglodytes that literally don't understand extensions. As I am writing this one of them is asking me why the Template has an error, while looking at the exclamation point in the file icon.   As long as you don't tell them I won't.